# Java Apache Camel XML JSON marshal creates At-Signs

Tags: java, json, xml, apache-camel

I have two questions:
 1. Why are the @-Signs created in the json-file?
 2. Why ist the process still running after the xml-json marshalling? (look my EclipseConsole-Screenshot. I have to terminate the process every run.)

**MyRouteBuilder configure method**

```
public void configure() throws Exception{

    XmlJsonDataFormat xmlJsonFormat = new XmlJsonDataFormat();

    xmlJsonFormat.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    xmlJsonFormat.setForceTopLevelObject(true);
    xmlJsonFormat.setTrimSpaces(true);
    xmlJsonFormat.setRootName("newRoot");
    xmlJsonFormat.setSkipNamespaces(true);
    xmlJsonFormat.setRemoveNamespacePrefixes(true);
    xmlJsonFormat.setExpandableProperties(Arrays.asList("d", "e"));

    from("timer:timer1?period=100&repeatCount=1")
    .to("https://...foo")
    .marshal(xmlJsonFormat)
    .to("file:target/messages/others?noop=true&fileName=message.json");
}
```

**Input xml  - example segment**

```
<hotel name="Hotel foo" cat="5" mh="xxx"/>
<date from="2016-10-16" to="2016-10-18"/>
```

**Output json - example segment**

```
        "hotel" : {
        "@name" : "Hotel foo",
        "@cat" : "5",
        "@mh" : "xxx"
    },
    "date" : {
        "@from" : "2016-10-18",
        "@to" : "2016-10-19"
    },
```

[image: Eclipse Console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how XmlJson works out of the box, to differentiate whether a value is an XML attribute or XML value.

The JSon lib project which is what Camel uses is not so active developed anymore, so you may not be able to get them to add some functionality to configure whether to output `@` or not.